# Optimal way of creating a SortedSet from a number of HashMap objects

Tags: java, sorting, collections, hashmap, sortedset

I have a number of `HashMap` data structures containing hundreds of `Comparable` objects (say, of type `MyClass`) and need to put all the values (not the keys) in a single data structure, and then sort it.

Due to the volume and the arrival rate of `MyClass` objects, this procedure (performed at least once per millisecond) needs to be as efficient as possible.

An approach would be to use `SortedSet`, roughly as follows:

```
HashMap<String, MyClass>[] allMaps = ... // All the HashMaps

SortedSet<MyClass> set = new TreeSet<MyClass>();

Collection<MyClass> c;

for (HashMap<String, MyClass> m:allMaps)
{
    c = m.values();
    set.addAll(c);
}
```

It may be faster to pass a sorted collection to `set.addAll()`, which may re-sort the `TreeSet` on every insertion, or after every few insertions. However, to do so, a `List` needs to be passed to `Collections.sort()`, which means a conversion from `Collection` to `List` has to take place, i.e. another performance hit has to be sustained.

Also, there may be another, more efficient way of achieving the same goal.

Comments?

Comment: How much faster do you need it? If your maps only contain "hundreds" of objects, it shouldn't be a problem, unless you call that method every 50 ms... Also, I believe it would be faster to **first** create an unsorted set with all the values **then** pass that unsorted set to a sortedSet.addAll method. But I haven't tested it, so it is only a guess :-)

Comment: The way you're doing it is already the right way to go.  The `TreeSet` isn't entirely resorted on every insertion; it inserts elements in their correct sorted position.  Each `add` call is `O(log n)`.

Comment: Yes, my understanding as well - create one big unsorted collection, and then sort it. That way, the sort is only done once.

Calling Collections.sort() on the unsorted collection will probably be (slightly) faster than transferring the unsorted collection to a sorted collection.

It may or may not get optimized out anyway, but I'd avoid the intermediate collection in your code example, and do set.addAll(m.values);

Comment: The method is called much more often than once every 50 ms (at least once per 1 ms), so it is an issue. The problem with creating an unsorted collection is that it has to be a List for Collections.sort(), so the creation time of the List severely impacts the overall performance. Unless you guys can suggest a superfast way of doing so! :-)

Comment: Do you have to use a HashMap<x,y>[] to store your data in the first place?

Comment: @assylias I have to operate on a bunch of HashMap<String, MyClass> objects, so I was thinking of passing them to the handling method as a varargs array. But the HashMap<String, MyClass> cannot be avoided at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer kinda depends on how the MyClass data tends to change. For example, if you have a couple of new values coming in per timeframe, then you might want to consider keeping a hold of the last returned sorted set and a copy of the previous keys so that on the next run, you can just do a delta of the changes (i.e. find the new keys in the maps and manually insert them into the sorted set you returned last time).

This algorithm varies a bit if the MyClass objects might get removed from the maps. But the general thought is to make it faster, you have to find a way to perform incremental changes instead of reprocessing the whole set every time.

Comment: The MyClass data is usually totally different per round, so doing a delta is not very helpful. :-)

Comment: Oh wow. Okay. How much freedom do you have around the use of that HashMap[]? You could re-implement that whole array as a single data structure that keeps track of the sorted values as they are inserted.

Comment: As I wrote in the comments above, I have to operate on a bunch of HashMap<String, MyClass> objects, so I was thinking of passing them to the handling method as a varargs array. But the individual HashMap<String, MyClass> data structures cannot be avoided at this point.